# Struggling with limiting ::before to a single specified h2

Tags: html, css

This is what my code looks like. For this sake, I've deleted all the useless information.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="newsletter">
    <div class="newsletter_title">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col">
                <h2 class=".newsletter .newsletter_title">
                <span>Newsletter</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9 col">
                <div id="newsletter_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                        <h2 id="newsletter_embed_signup">Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                        <h3 id="newsletter_embed_signup">(And get a 10% voucher)</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, both `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags have different classes and id's assigned. In the css style sheet I address `.newsletter .newsletter_title h2::before` which then gets also applied to `#newsletter_embed_signup`. Pressumably because it shares the same container(?). What am I missing?

Comment: `.newsletter .newsletter_title h2` targets **any** `h2` element that is a *descendant* of an element with CSS class `newsletter_title` which in turn is a *descendant* of an element with CSS class `newsletter`.

Comment: You have duplicate `id` `newsletter_embed_signup`. Each id value can only be used ***once*** per HTML page. `id` - as the name says - is a unique **id**entifier that can only point to one element.

Answer (score 2):

To target the first `h2`, include the first h2's class name **`"newsletter"`** too in your selector like this:

```
.newsletter .newsletter_title h2.newsletter::before {
  /* style properties here */
}
```

---

To target the second `h2`, reference the h2's id **`"newsletter_embed_signup"`** in your selector like this:

```
#newsletter_embed_signup::before {
  /* style properties here */
}
```

The same approach above can be used for targeting your h3 elements too.

---

Also, unlike class names, IDs should be unique where each ID name can only be used once.

Either give a common class name to a group of your elements or assign unique IDs for each element.

Comment: `.newsletter .newsletter_title h2#newsletter_embed_signup::before` should be `#newsletter_embed_signup::before`.

Comment: @connexo Thanks for the heads up. Updating the answer.

Comment: `h2#newsletter_embed_signup::before` should be `#newsletter_embed_signup::before`.

Comment: @connexo Thanks yet again for the heads up lol Answer updated.

Comment: *The same approach above can be used for targeting your h3 elements too.* This fails to mention that OP is using duplicate id `newsletter_embed_signup`.

Comment: @connexo Oh yes. I didn't notice that earlier. I'm on my phone now. Will edit the answer in a bit mate.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of AndrewL64 is perfectly correct. Just wanted to point out, that you shouldn't be using the same ID multiple times like in the example below:

```
<h2 id="newsletter_embed_signup">Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<h3 id="newsletter_embed_signup">(And get a 10% voucher)</h3>
```

Otherways you are going to run in further problems very soon so use classes instead.

Comment: This is correct, but it's not only "you shouldn't" but it's "you must not".